# TFS 2013.2 Installation Error

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, installation

Last night while attempting to upgrade from TFS 2013 RTM to TFS 2013.2 I received the following error. I ran the installation as administrator, I am the TFS Administrator for our organization and I ran the upgrade from TFS 2013 RTM to TFS 2013.2 in our staging environment without issue. The only difference in the two environments is the collection DBs are not exactly the same.

```
[Error  @22:27:44.807] 
Exception Message: TF255077: The access control list (ACL) could not be set on the following path:  D:\TFS\CacheRoot . (type ConfigurationException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.FileSystemHandler.SetAcls(String[] identities, String[] pathsForAccess, Boolean skipIfAclExists, ITFLogger logger)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ConfigureSetAcls.Run(ActivityContext context)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: Invalid name.
Parameter name: name (type ArgumentException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName, ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity..ctor(Boolean isContainer, ResourceType resourceType, String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity..ctor(String name, AccessControlSections includeSections)
   at System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl(String path)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.FileSystemHandler.AddAccessToDirectory(String groupName, FileSystemRights rights, String path, Boolean skipIfAclExists, ITFLogger logger)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.FileSystemHandler.SetAcls(String[] identities, String[] pathsForAccess, Boolean skipIfAclExists, ITFLogger logger)

[Info   @22:27:44.807] Node returned: Error
[Error  @22:27:44.807] TF255077: The access control list (ACL) could not be set on the following path:  D:\TFS\CacheRoot .
[Info   @22:27:44.807] Completed SetApplicationACLs: Error
[Info   @22:27:44.807] -----------------------------------------------------
[Info   @22:27:44.808] Execution results:
[Info   @22:27:44.808] Overall result: Failure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was discovered that there were spaces on either end of the folder location entry in the web.config file in the following location; C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services.

add key="dataDirectory" value=" D:\TFS\CacheRoot "

I removed the spaces and the installation worked perfectly. I have no idea how they got there but it is my assumption that the original TFS 2013 RTM installation may have done this as I pointed the installation to that folder when given the option during setup.